# Is the Euclidean norm the only norm that admits "non-reflective" isometries?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb R^n$, and suppose there exists an isometry $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ that is not simply a composition of reflections along some of the $n$ axes. That is, $T$ is linear, preserves $\|\cdot\|$, and there exists some standard basis element $e_i$ such that $Te_i\neq\pm e_i.$ Suppose further that $\|e_i\|=1$ for each $1\leqslant i\leqslant n,$ where $\{e_i\}$.

**Conjecture:** Under these assumptions $\|\cdot\|$ must be the standard Euclidean norm.

Is this true? My intuition says yes, but I have no idea where to begin proving it.

(This question is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154187/is-the-euclidean-norm-canonical) one.)

Comment: A product of a Euclidean space and an arbitrary normed space has non-reflection symmetries, so to characterize the Euclidean norm more is needed. Transitivity of the isometry group on the unit sphere (a.k.a., isotropy at the origin) looks offhand to be necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think I understand your first statement, but as for the second, can you define transitivity of the isometry group?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Actually I'm not sure I understand the first statement either. Can you provide a counterexample in $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: For the first, take the Euclidan norm $\|\ \|_{2}$ on $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ and any norm $|\ |$ on $\mathbf{R}^{n-2}$, and define $\|(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)\|=\|(x_1,x_2)\|_{2} + |(x_3,\dots,x_n)|$. This is a norm, and has rotational symmetries, but is not the Euclidean norm. For the second, to each norm on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, we can consider the _isometry group_ of linear transformations satisfying $\|Tx-Ty\|=\|x-y\|$ for all $x$, $y$. For the Euclidean norm, if $e$ and $e'$ are unit vectors, there exists an isometry $T$ satisfying $Te=e'$ ("isometries act transitively").

Answer (score 2):

A norm is fully characterized by its unit ball which must be compact convex and symmetric about the origin.  An isometry must preserve the unit ball.  Now, if you take the plane for instance and the unit ball to be a regular 2n polygon, it has some finite group of rotations as symmetries.  These rotations may be products of reflections, but I don't think all of them are generated by reflections about the x and y axis.

Comment: Can you define "symmetric about the origin"?

Comment: If x is in it then -x is in it.